# pass a var from one page to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, innerhtml

I have a page (#1) that has an include of another page (#2). The second page contains a db query. I need to be able to pass a message to the first page if there are no results. Can it be done with jQuery or something like innerHTML?

Would I need to put message container in page 1 and target that area from page 2?

Page #1

```
<div id="messageArea"></div>
```

Page #2

```
if ($error === true) {
    $message = 'Message here';
}
```

UPDATE: The include is called with AJAX

Comment: What is "an include of another page"? SSI? PHP? An iframe? Fetching the page through AJAX and inserting it into the DOM?

Comment: Alex Sexton did a talk on cross-page communication http://alexsexton.com/

Comment: Who thought this question was useful? Not nearly enough details for anyone to help

Answer (score 1):

Put the value in the query string and parse the query string on the receiving page.

Comment: XSS incoming in... 3... 2... 1... no really, make sure that there's no script tag in the message etc.